# Insert query to insert into a MySQL database does not work. (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert values from a **form** and insert it onto a MySQL database.
But it does not work.
I'm a beginner,please help.

**Here is my Code:**

```
<?php

function register(){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
//echo $name;

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "LinuxCreditSociety");
$rs = $con->query("insert into cust_mst (customer_id,customer_name,customer_address,customer_mobile,email_id)values(1003,'$name','$address','$phone','$email')");
$rs->free();
$con->close();
}

?>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="phpcss.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:300px;top:5px">
            <h1 align="center"><font face="Purisa" size="20" color="purple">Linux Credit Society</font></h1>
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute;right:160px;top:5px"><img src="linux.jpg" height="150" /></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:140px;top:5px"><img src="linux.jpg" height="150" /></div>


    <form method="post">
        <div class="st1">
         Name:</br></br>
         Address:</br></br>
         Email-id:</br></br>
         Phone#:</br></br>
        </div>
        <div class="st2">
            <div style="position:absolute;top:5px">
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:78px">
                <input type="text" name="address"> 
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:148px">
              <input type="text" name="email">
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:218px">
                <input type="text" name="phone">
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:290px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Register">  
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:320px;">
                    <?php
                            if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Register")
                                register();
                  ?>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And this is how I have created my database:**

```
create database LinuxCreditSociety;

use LinuxCreditSociety;

create table cust_mst(
customer_id int,
customer_name varchar(50),
customer_address varchar(70),
customer_mobile double,
email_id varchar(50));

insert into cust_mst values(1001, 'Jack Mathew', 'Bandra', '9998887770', 'jackm@yahoo.com');

insert into cust_mst values(1002, 'Jill Roberts', 'Dadar', '999665550', 'jillr@rediff.com');
```

EDIT:

Guys I just made one change and it worked thankyou.Now I will work on Injections as well!!

**Here is what I did:**

I just changed the call from ->

```
    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Register")
                            register();
              ?>
```

to this ->

```
<?php
                                if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != "")
                                    register();
                      ?>
```

Comment: please explain **what does no work**

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it does not work"?

Comment: Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: use mysql_error  like if (!mysql_query("insert into  .........", $link)) {    echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
} , link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php

Comment: It does not insert values in the Database.Insert Query does not fire.

Comment: another thing sanitize the data you get from the user, read about sql injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you want this the other way around:

```
$_POST[name] = $name;
$_POST[address] = $address;
$_POST[email] = $email;
$_POST[phone] = $phone;
```

eg:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

Comment: And even then, `$_POST['name']` would make a lot more sense than `$_POST[name]`

Comment: Sorry I have changed it now.That was a huge mistake on my part.But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I assume your data is coming from `$_POST`. Change

```
$_POST[name] = $name;
$_POST[address] = $address;
$_POST[email] = $email;
$_POST[phone] = $phone;
```

Into

```
$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$address = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
```

Note the use of [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in order to prevent [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, since you're already using the `mysqli` extension, consider building [prepared statements](http://devzone.zend.com/article/686) rather than interpolating variables into the query string.

Last side note: to prevent error notices like "Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in /your/script", access array keys using strings (i.e. `$_POST['name']` instead of `$_POST[name]`).

Comment: have you ever used prepared statements yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but dont forget to sanitize your variables !!!

```
function register(){

    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $address    = $_POST['address'];
    $phone      = $_POST['email'];
    $email      = $_POST['phone'];

    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "LinuxCreditSociety");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if (!$con->query("insert into cust_mst (customer_id,customer_name,customer_address,customer_mobile,email_id)values(NULL,'$name','$address','$phone','$email')")) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $con->error);
    }

    $con->close();
}
```

Comment: @Pavitar its terrible idea to expose your errors to everyone. trigger_error() should be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
function register(){

    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $address    = $_POST['address'];
    $phone      = $_POST['email'];
    $email      = $_POST['phone'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "LinuxCreditSociety");
    $rs = $con->query("insert into cust_mst (customer_id,customer_name,customer_address,customer_mobile,email_id)values(NULL,'{$name}','{$address}','{$phone}','{$email}')");
    $rs->free();
    $con->close();
}
```

Comment: > It still doesn't work.Can you please explain why you have used {} ?